# Conditional structure — 'if' and 'elif' — doesn't show the correct result

Tags: python, if-statement, methods, conditional-statements

the program should show me the right result. For example, if cor equals 'vermelho', print ('sua paleta equivale ao por do sol'), but isn't working.

```
class Bola:

    def escolha(self, cor):
        self.cor = cor

    def paleta(self):
        if self.cor == 'vermelho' or 'laranja' or 'lilas' or 'amarelo':
            print('sua paleta equivale ao por do sol')
        elif self.cor == 'azul' or 'branco':
             print('sua paleta equivale ao ceu')
        else:
             print('paleta nao definida')

bola = Bola()
bola.escolha('azul')
bola.paleta()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statements as you have them are like this:

```
if a == 'b' or 'c':
    print('xyz')
```

This is asking: If a has a value of 'b' or if 'c' is True, print('xyz'). What you need to do is:

```
if a == 'b' or a == 'c':
    print('xyz')
```

This will (hopefully) give you the result you want. Another way to do it:

```
correct_responses = ['b', 'c', 'd']
if a in correct_responses:
    print('xyz')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: nice, man! 
this solution also helped me, thanks a friend

Answer (score 0):

The `or` operator doesn't work the way you're using it.  Use:

```
        def paleta(self):
            if self.cor in {'vermelho', 'laranja', 'lilas', 'amarelo'}:
                print('sua paleta equivale ao por do sol')
            elif self.cor in {'azul', 'branco'}:
                 print('sua paleta equivale ao ceu')
            else:
                 print('paleta nao definida')
```

`or` tests whether either of two expressions is true; it doesn't create a set of expressions that you can test for equality against.  For that you want to use a `set` (e.g. `{'azul', 'branco'}`) and the `in` operator.

Comment: hey Samwise, thanks!

Comment: I hadn't thought about this syntax, man thanks for the tip, really, I'm very happy that it worked